# Change axis range in Matlab stem plot

Tags: matlab, graphics, matlab-figure, axes

The x-axis range seems to begin at the first data point and end at the last by default. I'd like to extend this a little bit in both directions so my graph looks zoomed out a bit. How do I set this? I don't see it in the stem documentation.

example code:

```
f = [0.0 0.45 0.55 1.0];
a = [1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0];

filter = firpm(10,f,a);

plot(f,a);
stem(filter);
```

and I want to change the x-axis from 0 to 20 (it currently defaults at 1 to 11).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not done by `stem` or any other plotting function. To control axis range you use either [`axis`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html):

> `axis(limits)` specifies the limits for the current axes. Specify the limits as vector of four, six, or eight elements. [...]

or [`xlim`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html):

> `xlim(limits)` specifies the x-axis limits for the current axes. Specify limits as a two-element vector of the form `[xmin xmax]`, where `xmax` is greater than `xmin`. [...] 
>   `xl = xlim` returns a two-element vector containing the current limits. [...]

For example, to extend the current range of the *x* axis 1 unit to each side:

```
xlim(xlim + [-1 1])
```

(note that this uses the two types of calls described in the `xlim` documentation excerpts above).

Or, in your specific example,

```
xlim([0 20])
```